# Wrong number of products in category

Tags: product, category-products

I have a problem, one of our categories is showing a wrong number of products. When I go to categories in the backend the number stands on 164 products. When I look at the products tab, there are only 22 products selected.
This wouldn’t have bothered me if the frontend showed me the 22 selected products, but it shows 128 products.

Has anybody heard of this problem before and (how) were you able to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's a feature.
The categories with the attribute `Is Anchor` set to `Yes` display the products in the subcategories also.
If you don't want this to happen, set `Is Anchor` to `No`.
You may also need to rebuild your indexes when you are done.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job!! I've been searching for this for hours.