# Wrong number of products even after reindex?

Tags: magento2, category, indexing

I was meet a very strange issue with Magento 2 number of products. There has a question here on Magento StackExchange: [Wrong number of products in category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/wrong-number-of-products-in-category). But my situation is different to him.

In my categories, there are no subcategories nor any products. But the number inside brackets is 1xxx. I tried to reindex (clear cache...) millions of millions times, but there is no luck, still same result.

Anyone here ever met this before me? Or better if you knew what was happened.

Answer (score 2):

Try Clearing the magento cache , or bulk deleting your products then reimporting them all , then try reindexing all of your products .

Comment: There is no cache.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/wrong-number-of-products-in-category

Comment: Did you really read my question?